# How to use grep to look for a special character from the command line parameters?

Tags: bash

I use grep to search for a specific character from command line parameters.

I wrote the following in my script:

```
isPath=$( $1|grep -c -q '/' )
```

But I keep getting the warning message: no such file or directory.

I just want to treat the first argument as a normal string and search for a specific character!! It seems very hard to do it!

Any help!

Comment: You need to `echo` the argument to grep instead of trying to run it as a command or use `<<<$1` to pass it to grep on standard input via a herestring.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
isPath=$( echo "$1"|grep -c '/' )
```

The quotes may not be necessary in this case, but it is good practice to use them generally.

Comment: Thanks! But when my $1 contains actually 1 '/', the value of isPath cannot be displayed?? Why is that?

Comment: Because you use '-q' to suppress all output from grep... try removing it.